# Why can one not use storage directives .db, .dw to declare variables to be stored in SRAM?

Tags: assembly, avr

Hey guys studying up for a final and I am not sure how to answer this. I know the answer is no, but I do not know why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your program gets written into the flash (aka. program memory) you can only define data there. Of course you might have an initialization routine that copies a range of bytes from flash to sram, and your toolchain might even support such usage transparently. For example, the `avr-gcc` toolchain uses the `.data` section like that.

Given this C code fragment:

```
static unsigned char foo[] = { 1, 4, 9, 16 };
```

`avr-gcc` will create the following assembly code (excerpt):

```
        .data
        .type   foo.1351, @object
        .size   foo.1351, 4
foo.1351:
        .byte   1
        .byte   4
        .byte   9
        .byte   16
```

The final program will have this section embedded in flash, of course. The toolchain creates an initializer routine that copies it to sram, where the code expects it:

```
00000000 <__ctors_end>:
   0:   10 e0           ldi     r17, 0x00
   2:   a0 e6           ldi     r26, 0x60
   4:   b0 e0           ldi     r27, 0x00
   6:   e2 e2           ldi     r30, 0x22
   8:   f0 e0           ldi     r31, 0x00
   c:   c8 95           lpm
   e:   31 96           adiw    r30, 0x01
  10:   0d 92           st      X+, r0
  12:   a4 36           cpi     r26, 0x64
  14:   b1 07           cpc     r27, r17
  16:   d1 f7           brne    .-12
```

This is a loop using `lpm` to read from flash and `st X+, r0` to write to sram.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which tool set you're using, but in the case of Microsoft / ARM / and many other tool sets combined with some type of exe2bin utility to generate rom images for embedded software, then using db, dw, dd, dq, is not an issue for data in SRAM. The generated code will include code that copies data from the ROM / EPROM / EEPROM / FLASH image into SRAM at startup. For uninitialized memory you can use ? for the values such as | db ? | or | dw ? |. These normally go in to the .BSS (block started by symbol) segment. It's common for the start up code to zero out the uninitialized memory areas, so it can also place static variables in the .BSS section.